# Hide and Protect a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need help in google spreadsheet (Excel).
I have three persons, A,B,C and three pages of one spreadsheet ,
Sheet x, sheet y sheet z.
All sheets viewable and editable for Person A only
Sheet y and z viewable and editable for Person B and C.
The person C must be able to see only Sheet Z.
If its possible, please share method.
I have tried documentation and Youtube tutorials but not working for me.
Here is example sheet link which I have created
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1edP3vVxw9kMLRXF2f8quI5D6APdyXEkSM05_yiCbB2U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: create new spreadsheet and use IMPORTRANGE for person C

Comment: Importrange only copy data from one file to other. The other person's are not allowed to access peron C file unless they also open file C to modify.
So importrange is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @player0 you can create three different sheets for each one of the users.

You would be the editor on all the sheets.

Every specific user would be shared its sheet as a viewer of it, so he can't modify the sheet.

Then on the sheets you would use the function [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=) to select what do you want to share on that sheet.

For example for **person C** you would do:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MASTER SHEET ID", "Z!A:Z")
```

Comment: Importrange function only allow to fetch and show the data from other file or files.
The person A is not allowed to modify the data from single sheet. He have to go to other files and then edit the cells.
I want to enable Person A to control/ modify all files from a single file which is not possible with Import range.

Comment: What would those different users be doing on the sheets? If they can modify it, wouldn't be better that each user had its own sheet and then you do an IMPORTRANGE of each sheet in one master to see what they are doing? Can you please describe the workflow? Also, the spreadsheet you posted on the original question requires access, could you share it publicly?

Comment: My shared sheet is disabled right now.
The boss person want to save his time and work on only 1 sheet( edit, delete etc), other person's may work on their allowed pages/sheet but unable to see others data. 
If boss make 3 sheets and gives access with limitation, the boss can work on 1 sheet which consume a lot of time to switch the sheets.